# How to point to first element when object.next reached the end?

Tags: ruby

An enum object is created from array `a`. Are there any methods to point to the `.first` when `.next` reaches the end.

```
a = [5,1]
b = a.to_enum

b.next #=> 5
b.next #=> 1
b.next #=> Stop Iteration: Iteration reached an end.
```

Is it possible to point to first element so that I can use next again or point to previous element or loop through?

```
b.prev #=> undefined method
b.previous #=> undefined method
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Enumeration#rewind`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind).

```
a = [5, 1]
b = a.to_enum
b.next
# 5
b.next
# 1
b.next
# StopIteration: iteration reached at end
b.rewind
b.next
# 5
# etc
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use [cycle](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle)

```
b.cycle(2) {|x| puts x} 

#=> 5
#=> 1
#=> 5
#=> 1
```

If you want to run it forever just don't pass a parameter to cycle. And you could invoke this directly on your array object i.e. `a`

Answer (score 3):

```
b = a.to_enum.cycle
```

See the documentation for cycle:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle