# Ruby: Loop back Enumerator

Tags: ruby, enumerator

Is there a way to loop back an enumerator in Ruby? Given this piece of code:

```
a=[1,2,3]
a.to_enum

a.next => 1
a.next => 2
a.next => 3
a.next => 1
```

How can I make the `next` method go back to the first element when the enumerator reached the last element?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`Enumerable#cycle`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-cycle):

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
enum = a.cycle  #=> #<Enumerator: [1, 2, 3]:cycle>

enum.next       #=> 1
enum.next       #=> 2
enum.next       #=> 3
enum.next       #=> 1
```

Comment: Hi thx saving my day, but how can i get the current value that the pointer points to?

Comment: @KitHo use [`Enumerator#peek`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-peek), e.g. `enum = a.cycle; enum.peek`

Comment: The docs said : Returns the next object in the enumerator, but doesn’t move the internal position forward. If the position is already at the end, StopIteration is raised.

Sometime i just want to inspect what current value that the internal pointer is pointing to.

Comment: Normally you would just save it in a variable. Using `peek` you can acheive the same thing by just calling `next` *after* you have consumed the output, not before.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use `rewind` [Enumerator.html#rewind](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-rewind)

```
a.rewind
```

Exactly same question I asked some time ago [how-to-point-to-first-element-when-object-next-reached-the-end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650983/how-to-point-to-first-element-when-object-next-reached-the-end)